How to properly stream audio with flutter and just_audio
So what I am doing is that I am sending text to eleven labs streaming api and am getting back raw audio data that I am playing using just_audio package.
Another function of mine starts the _fetchAudioData function here and I get the audio data and start playing it.
Future<Uint8List?> _fetchAudioData(String text) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            'https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${widget.voiceId}/stream'),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'xi-api-key': dotenv.env['ELEVENLABSKEY']!,
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          "text": text.replaceAll('*', ''),
          "model_id": myModel,
          "voice_settings": widget.voiceSetting
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.bodyBytes;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  void _playNextAudio() {
    if (_audioQueue.isNotEmpty) {
      Uint8List audioData = _audioQueue.removeFirst();
      _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(MyCustomSource(audioData));
      _audioPlayer.play();
      _audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
        if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
          _audioPlayer.stop();
          _playNextAudio();
        }
      });
    }
  }

MyCustomSource is : 

class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final List<int> bytes;
  MyCustomSource(this.bytes);

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}

Now the issue is that although audio plays it waits for all the audio data to arrive and then only starts playing. But what I want to do is that properly stream it as in the moment first chunk of the audio data arrives it should start playing.

hey did you get this working? Id appreciate if you shared your code if you did. Im doing the same thing

This should be your source class for controlling real time stream
class VoiceSource extends StreamAudioSource {
    final StreamController<List<int>> _controller =
          StreamController<List<int>>.broadcast();List<int> bytes = [];
    
      void addBytes(List<int> chunk) {
        bytes.addAll(chunk);
        _controller.add(chunk);
      }
    
      void removeListener() {
        _controller.close();
      }
    
      @override
      Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
        start ??= 0;
        end ??= bytes.length;
        return StreamAudioResponse(
          sourceLength: bytes.length,
          contentLength: end - start,
          offset: start,
          stream: _controller.stream,
          contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
        );
      }
    }

for identifying wheather the first chunk has arrived you can take a boolean flag and an empty bytes list initially to cater your streaming audio.
     bool fetchingResponse = true;
     List<int> bytes = [];
     final voiceSource = VoiceSource();

     Stream stream = data.stream;
        stream.listen(
          (chunk) {
            bytes.addAll(chunk);
            voiceSource.addBytes(chunk);
            if (bytes.isNotEmpty && fetchingResponse) {
              fetchingResponse = false
              // your first chunk has arrived here  
              // add audio to your list of messages here.
              // this if will only be called once because of the flag
              // update your UI        
            }
          },
          onDone: () {
          // do something here, your stream has finished collecting the data.
// you can use your list of bytes here to do something
          },
          onError: (error) {},
          cancelOnError: true,
        );

finally, just after the stream, call your player.
await player.setAudioSource(voiceSource, preload: false);


Hi, can you please help. I tried this approach and did this :
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
response.stream.listen(
          (chunk) {
            print("we are listening");
        bytes.addAll(chunk);
        voiceSource.addBytes(chunk);

But even though I get 200 status code and it prints we are listening continuously, I keep getting error saying [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: HttpException: Content size exceeds specified contentLength. 1366 bytes written while expected 2. [^²Ìo^P¤lð'\¡:S^W'´ÛØ®:Ú

sure, so since our stream is dynamically increasing we can do something like this in our VoiceSource class.
return StreamAudioResponse(
sourceLength: null,
contentLength: null
// rest remains same
);
in this way the stream now has dynamic content and hence this issue should now get resolved.
also you should call:
voiceSource.removeLIstener();
method in the onDone callback of the stream like this:
Stream stream = data.stream;
stream.listen(
onDone: () {
voiceSource.removeListener();
},
);

Hi, first of all thanks for trying to help. But now I am getting "[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      _proxyHandlerForSource.handler (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:3235:64)"
It has been the same, one error or another trying to make stream work properly. It works if I wait for entire audio chunk to get collected first but I want to start audio as soon as first chunk arrives, true streaming.

The error iis because just_audio doesn't expects a null for contentLength.
The offending line of code in just audio is :
if (rangeRequest != null && sourceResponse.offset != null) {
final range = _HttpRangeResponse(
sourceResponse.offset!,
sourceResponse.offset! + sourceResponse.contentLength! - 1,
sourceResponse.sourceLength);

So I gave it an arbitrary large length and it played but it always plays from midway, its missing first couple of chunks and starts in middle.

I am also working on this same feature of implementing streaming audio and starting it as soon as the first set of data arrives from server, I found out this issue from the justAudio team:
https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/1135
check this out, its the same thing that we are trying to achieve and I am also getting this issue of missing first couple of chunks of the audio, I think it is a genuine issue in the library itself
maybe we have to go with another way of implementing it

Ah well, thanks for helping out. Please let me know if you can implement this with another player

Looks like it is possibe.
Audio source class should handle audio bytes that will be fed to the stream of StreamAudioResponse:
class AppAudioStreamSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  AppAudioStreamSource() {
    _controller.stream.listen((chunk) {
      bytes.addAll(chunk);
    });
  }

  final _controller = StreamController<List<int>>.broadcast();
  final List<int> bytes = [];

  void addBytes(List<int> chunk) {
    if (!_controller.isClosed) {
      _controller.add(chunk);
    }
  }

  void close() {
    _controller.close();
  }

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    final startPos = start ??= 0;
    final endPos = end ??= bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: bytes.length,
      contentLength: endPos - startPos,
      offset: startPos,
      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}

Then most tricky part. Some pseudocode here.
Somewhere in your cubit/provider/class:
final _appAudioStreamSource = AppAudioStreamSource();

then you should have some stream from where you got your audio data(assume list of int). and you start listen it and set bytes from it to source instance:
... audioDataStream.listen(List<int> chunk) async {
    _appAudioStreamSource.addBytes(chunk);
  });

and important part here - when set source? you should it do after you have got you data, e.g first property:
 unawaited(
      ...audioDataStream.first.whenComplete(() async {
        await _audioHandler.setSource(_appAudioStreamSource);
        ...
      }),
    );


To play raw PCM bytes, shall use flutter_pcm_sound
Initialize player with,
await FlutterPcmSound.setup(sampleRate: 16000, channelCount: 1);
await FlutterPcmSound.play();

then feed PCM bytes as they arrive,
await FlutterPcmSound.feed(PcmArrayInt16(bytes: pcmBytes));

This library also has support for buffering.
